# Can't get static param value

Tags: yii2, parameters

I have error Unknown Method

> Calling unknown method: yii\web\Application::params()

Model:

```
public static function isSecretKeyExpire($key)
{
    if (empty($key))
        return false;
    $expire = Yii::$app->params('secretKeyExpire');
    $parts = explode('_', $key);
    $timestamp = (int) end($parts);
    return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way :

```
 Yii::$app->params['versionDate'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Yii::app()->params['secretKeyExpire']
```

Comment: Your notation should be for Yii1,  the question is for Yii2